# htaccess url rewrite affecting internal urls?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My url looks like this:

```
website.com/proj1/post.php?id=130
```

and I want to rewrite to:

```
 website.com/proj1/post/130
```

and the following htaccess rules rewrites the url for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)/?$ /proj1/post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but the problem is that the rules are affecting the internal urls as well.

for example rewriting

```
<img src="/images/ex.jpg" />
```

to

```
<img src="post/images/ex.jpg" />
```

Is there a way to exclude the internal links ?

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines will ignore rewrite rules if the file or folder physically exist

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
   RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: Thats not the issue here. See the linked post.